# HVAC has filters on returns only

Tags: hvac, air-filter

New home purchase and was surprised that the heat pump air handler does not have a filter inserted.  The filters are on the returns only, but are very well fitted.  There are two returns.

Is this an acceptable approach?  If it is actually designed this way would inserting an air filter create too much resistance for the air handler?

The coils seemed squeaky clean to my eye.

Minor subplot - the location of the condensate line makes it awkward to change the filter.  You have to unscrew the condensate line to install it.  Is there a better way to run this line assuming that we should actually have a filter inserted?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the air is filtered at the intakes of the return ducts, where is it going to get dirty on the way to the air handler to need filtered again?

Maintain the ones you have, don't add more where you don't need them...